# Mongoose possible issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have an issue using mongoose.
The application I am writing consists in a file watcher that notifies clients about certain events via email and socketio messages.

I made an example that shows the problem:
basically, there is a class called `mainFileWatcher` that contains a `submodule` which in turn watches for new files or folders created in the script directory, emitting an "event" event when that happens. The `mainFileWatcher` listens for that event and calls a static method of a mongoose `Client` model.

If you run the script setting `REPL=true` you'll be able to access a `watcher.submodule` object and manually `emit` an "event" event.

Now, if you manually trigger the event, you'll see a statement that 
says that the "event" event was triggered and an email address as a response.
Otherwhise, if you create a file or a folder in the script folder, you'll 
just see that statement. Actually, if you run the script with `REPL=true`
you'll get the email only after pressing any key, nothing otherwise.

The fact that you don't get the email address as a response means to me that 
the code in the promise in mongoose model doesn't get called for some reason.

Here is the code, sorry I couldn't make it shorter

```
// run
// npm install mongoose bluebird inotify underscore
//
// If you run the script with REPL=true you get an interactive version
// that has as context the filewatcher that emit events in my original code.
// It can be acessed through the watcher.submodule object.
// The watcher triggers a "event" event when you create a file or a folder in the script
// directory.
//
// If you emit manually an "event" event with the watcher.submodule in the repl, you should see a
// statement that "event" was triggered and
// an email address (that belongs to a fake client created by the bootstrap
// function at startup).
// If instead you create a file or a folder in the script folder (or whatever folder you have setted),
// you should see this time you'll have no email response. Actually, if you run with REPL=true,
// you'll have no email response untill you press any key. If you run without REPL, you'll
// have no email response.

'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var EventEmitter = require('events');
var util = require('util');
var _ = require("underscore");
var Inotify = require('inotify').Inotify;
var inotify = new Inotify();

// Schema declaration
var clientSchema = new Schema({
  emails: {
    type: [String]
  }
}, {strict:false});

clientSchema.statics.findMailSubscriptions = function (subscription, cb) {
  this.find({
    subscriptions: {$in: [subscription]},
    mailNotifications: true
  }).exec().then(function (clients) {
      if(!clients || clients.length === 0) return cb(null, null);
      var emails = [];
      clients.forEach(function (client) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(emails, client.emails)
      });
      return cb(null, emails);
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.error(err);
    })
};

var clientModel = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);

// Mongoose connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function (err, db) {
  if (err) console.error('Mongoose connect error: ', err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  console.log('Mongoose connected');
});

// bootstrap function: it inserts a fake client in the database
function bootstrap() {
  clientModel.findOne({c_id: "testClient"}).then(function (c) {
    if(!c) {
      var new_c = new clientModel({
        "name": "Notifier",
        "c_id": "testClient",
        "subscriptions": ["orders"],
        "registeredTo": "Daniele",
        "emails": ["email@example.com"],
        "mailNotifications": true
      });
      new_c.save(function(err){
        if (err) console.error('Bootstrap Client Error while saving: ', err.message  );
      });
    }
  });
}

// submodule of the main file watcher: it looks for new files created in the script dir
var submoduleOfFileWatcher = function() {
  var _this = this;
  var handler = function (event) {
    var mask = event.mask;
    var type = mask & Inotify.IN_ISDIR ? 'directory' : 'file';
    if (mask & Inotify.IN_CREATE) {
      _this.emit("event", event);
    }
  }
  var watcher = {
    path: '.', // here you can change the path to watch if you want
    watch_for: Inotify.IN_CREATE,
    callback: handler
  }

  EventEmitter.call(this);
  this.in_id = inotify.addWatch(watcher);
}
util.inherits(submoduleOfFileWatcher, EventEmitter);

// Main File Watcher (it contains all the submodules and listensto the events emitted by them)
var mainFileWatcher = function () {
  this.start = function() {
    bootstrap();
    _.bindAll(this, "onEvent");
    this.submodule = new submoduleOfFileWatcher();
    this.submodule.on("event", this.onEvent)
  };
  this.onEvent = function() {
    console.log("event triggered");
    clientModel.findMailSubscriptions("orders", function(err, mails) {
      if (err) console.error(err);
      console.log(mails); // THIS IS THE CODE THAT OUTPUTS ONLY IF YOU TRIGGER THE "event" EVENT manually
    })
  }
}

// Instantiate and start the watcher
var watcher = new mainFileWatcher()
watcher.start();

// start the repl if asked
if (process.env.REPL === "true") {
  var repl = require('repl');
  var replServer = repl.start({
    prompt: 'filewatcher via stdin> ',
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  replServer.context.watcher = watcher;
}
```

Just copy and paste the code, install deps and run it.

Things I tried:

I changed the mongoose Promise object to use bluebird promises, hoping that
I could intercept some exception.

I browsed Mongoose calls with node-inspector and indeed the find method gets called and it seems that it throws no exceptions. I really can't figure out what's happening because I don't get any errors at all.

It is not the database connection (I tried to open one just before the `findMailSubscriptions` call and got an exception for trying to open an already opened connection). 
I figure it might be some issues with scopes or promises.

Is there something I am missing about mongoose, or is it just my code that causes this behaviour?

Comment: "*`if (!cb || typeof cb !== "function") return cb("You must provide a cb function", null);`*" - chuckle :-)

Comment: Hm, given that you're using Bluebird makes it unlikely that you've got an unhandled rejection, but still I want to mention that you are not reporting errors from the promise - and if it gets rejected, your success callback of course never gets called.

Comment: Yes you are right, the code i posted doesn't report errors. I have tried (before asking this question, sorry for not mentioning) to chain a .catch(function(err)..)  call after the .then(), nothing in both blocks get called.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you simplify it down to a [MCVE]?

Comment: I tried to simplifiy it down and edited the post. You can copy the script, install the deps and run it. Hope it is ok.

Comment: @Bergi: about the line of code you reported, it wasn't me..:-) it was my dog that wrote it. I can be even more stupid!

Comment: @JohnnyHK: is this example better?